# Application Insights - Logging exceptions

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I wrote a custom logger for Application Insights in my app. I don't see any exceptions or ANY events when viewing App Insights in Azure Portal. Here is the logger class code, when I debug the code I do see a key assigned to the InstrumentationKey property, any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Do I need to attach other info to the client or configuration?

```cs
public class AppInsightsLogger:ILogger
{
    private TelemetryClient ai;

    public AppInsightsLogger()
    {
        ai = new TelemetryClient();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ai.InstrumentationKey))
        {
            // attempt to load instrumentation key from app settings
            var appSettingsTiKey = AppSettings.InsightsKey;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appSettingsTiKey))
            {
                TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = appSettingsTiKey;
                ai.InstrumentationKey = appSettingsTiKey;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not find instrumentation key for Application Insights");
            }
        }
    }
    public void LogException(Exception ex)
    {
        ai.TrackException(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I created a new Console Application, installed latest stable ApplicationInsights SDK and pretty much kept your example, with minor but important difference - I either let it wait before shutting down after calling TrackException or added TelemetryClient.Flush()

```cs
namespace logtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppInsightsLogger logger = new AppInsightsLogger();
            logger.LogException(new InvalidOperationException("Is data showing?"));

            // either wait for a couple of minutes for the batch to be sent of add ai.Flush() after ai.TrackException() to send the batch immediately
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class AppInsightsLogger
    {
        private TelemetryClient ai;

        public AppInsightsLogger()
        {
            ai = new TelemetryClient();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ai.InstrumentationKey))
            {
                // attempt to load instrumentation key from app settings
                var appSettingsTiKey = "<ikey>";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appSettingsTiKey))
                {
                    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = appSettingsTiKey;
                    ai.InstrumentationKey = appSettingsTiKey;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Could not find instrumentation key for Application Insights");
                }
            }
        }
        public void LogException(Exception ex)
        {
            ai.TrackException(ex);
            // ai.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

First I could see telemetry item sent in Visual Studio debug output window:
[image]

Then I could see telemetry leaving my machine in Fiddler, I also could see it was successfully accepted by our data collection endpoint.
[image]

And finally I could see it in the portal:

[image]

Comment: `TelemetryClient.Flush()` helped.

Answer (score 8):

Nowadays, the question and the accepted answer are outdated. The contemporary approach is to add `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet` NuGet package, which has logging out-of-the-box.

Please refer to [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger).

The gist from the docs:

1. `ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider` is enabled by default.
2. Captured log types can be configured in `appsettings.json` (or programmatically if you really need it)

```
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
        },
        "ApplicationInsights": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Error"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks...that really helped ! I had enabled app insights from Azure portal and it was showing my trace information and when i enabled it on my app via code the trace was not coming through... this was it !

Comment: The accepted answer is not outdated, it's just for .net framework, while this answer is for .net core.

Comment: Ah. This is awesome.. so if I have you correct @Alex Klaus , I don't have to explicitly call my logger in a catch block... the Application Insights SDK just grabs it for me and sends it to AI? Will it grab the entire exception object for me to view in the portal?

Comment: @spencer741, yes, you understand it correctly. Under the hood it adds middleware that hooks up in the pipeline and handles exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

For a version 3 webjob, I tried instantiating a TelemetryClient and calling TrackException(), as well as calling Flush() and waiting up to 180 seconds, but none of that worked. What does work is using the ILogger logger object and passing the exception into LogError().