# ApplicationInsights TrackException() is not logging stacktrace

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

`ApplicationInsights TrackException()` is not logging a stacktrace.

The call is very simple, something like this:

```
this.telemetry.TrackException(ex, properties);
```

The exception (of course thrown & caught) was having a stacktrace when passed to TrackException().

The json produces by application insights is something like this (I can see it in the output window):

```
{
  "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ff0c6b7759fa46cdbec661fecb9efb4d.Exception",
  "time": "2017-03-03T13:31:15.5946550Z",
  "iKey": "ff0c6b77-59fa-46cd-bec6-61fecb9efb4d",
  "tags": {
    "ai.cloud.roleInstance": "POSTAZIONE-DEV1",
    "ai.internal.sdkVersion": "dotnet:2.2.0-54037"
  },
  "data": {
    "baseType": "ExceptionData",
    "baseData": {
      "ver": 2,
      "properties": {
        "Keywords": "0x0000000000000000",
        "EventName": "ExceptionInHealthTrackerProc",
        "Level": "Always",
        "ProviderName": "Gamshy.RandomNumberGenerator.Service.ServiceEventSource",
        "EventId": "-1"
      },
      "exceptions": [
        {
          "id": 51763190,
          "typeName": "System.Exception",
          "message": "Tentativo di divisione per zero.",
          "hasFullStack": true
        }
      ]
   }
  }
}
```

The ApplicationInsights nuget package is Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.2.0

This is a screenshot of the data I can see querying from Analytics in the Azure portal.
[image]

Any idea? Is the AI library supposed not to log the stacktrace?

Comment: If you intercept the same telemetry item with Fiddler on its way out to dc.services.visualstudio.com - do you see exception stack in the body? I wonder if some optimization was applied to avoid too much info in the VS output.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35068786/7073340

Answer (score 0):

traceerror is limited in data, 
try this https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#TrackTrace