# Why is Application Insights TrackException not logging anything?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm currently trying to log exceptions in Application Insights for later investigation.
However, any exception I try to log with the TrackException method does not appear in Application Insights.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/diagnostic-search#filter-event-types) for Application Insights event filtering state the following:

> **Exception** - Uncaught exceptions in the server, and those that you log by using TrackException().

I'm using the following code to log my exception:

```
private static readonly TelemetryClient Client = new TelemetryClient{InstrumentationKey = ApplicationInsightsSettings.InstrumentationKey};

public static void TrackException(Exception exception, string traceReference)
{
    var properties = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"Trace Reference", traceReference}};

    Client.TrackException(exception);
    Client.TrackException(exception, properties);
    Client.TrackEvent(traceReference);
}
```

[Whenever I run this code **only** an event is logged but none of the exceptions are.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60u1E.png)

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048825/application-insights-logging-exceptions/35068786#35068786

Comment: where/how are you searching for the exceptions? on the azure portal or local env?

Comment: @Leonardo In the azure portal. The image in the bottom link shows my search criteria. (I couldn't embed it because I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: @abhinavpratap Flush seems to do nothing to fix the issue. I did however notice in the runtime output the following line: "filtered by SamplingTelemetryProcessor".

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this in UiPath so requirements may be a little different,
but when sending the exception I've had to add a Flush against the Telemetry Client

```
telemetryClient.TrackException(in_exception);
telemetryClient.Flush();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
```