# LogError(string) does not create entries in Application Insights Exception list

Tags: azure, containers, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

The following does not create entries in Exception list of app insights:

```
myLogger.LogError("something is wrong in {location}", "here")
```

Only the following do:

```
myLogger.LogError(new Exception("something is wrong here"))
myLogger.LogError(new Exception("something is wrong here"), "something is wrong in {location}", "here")
```

I guess one might call this a feature since the former is logging an error but not an exception. My philosophical approach on this is that an Error is also an Exception but an Exception isn't always an error (e.g. when it is handled).

In any case, the latter syntax does look a bit weird. Especially in the last case, I need to duplicate my message to take advantage of semantic logging.

I wonder if I'm looking at this in the wrong way.

Some more details about my implementation:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>xxxxxxxxxx</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.15.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.17.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

`builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]);`

```
  "Logging": {
     "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
}
```

},

Comment: Could you please share more details. What is the framework you are using?Please share your `.csproj` file .

Comment: @Harshitha sure. I amended my question.

Comment: What about your `appsetting.json` file. Mask your config values and please share it as well.

Comment: So, you are deploying your App to `Azure Docker Container`? Correct if Iam wrong.

Comment: Corrent. Deploying to App Service as a container.
I added my appsettings.json

Answer (score 0):

The code you have mentioned,

> ```cs
> myLogger.LogError(new Exception("something is wrong here"), "something is wrong in {location}", "here")
> ```

This will log both error and Exception.

In `appsettings.json` file change the Log level as below and check once.

Thanks @[Jay Krishna Reddy](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-azure-application-insights-for-exception-logging-in-c-sharp/) for the Cofiguration steps.

```cs
{  
  "Logging": {  
    "ApplicationInsights": {  
      "LogLevel": {  
        "Default": "Debug",  
        "Microsoft": "Error"  
      }  
    },  
      "LogLevel": {  
        "Default": "Information",  
        "Microsoft": "Warning",  
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"  
      }  
    },  
  "AllowedHosts": "*",  
  "ApplicationInsights": {  
    "InstrumentationKey": "Your Instrumentation Key",
    "CONNECTION_STRING" : "AppInsights Connection String"
  }  
}
```

The code which you have configured the Application Insights Connection string is fine.

```cs
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]);
```

Make sure you have added the respective connection string in `appsettings.json` file as well.

Also, we can use `TrackException` to log Exceptions in `Application Insights`.

Thanks @v-jbasden for the [Diagnose exceptions in web apps](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions.md).

As mentioned in the document, we can Use the `TelemetryClient` to log Exceptions.

```cs
try
{
}
catch (Exception myExcep) 
{ 
    TelemetryClient  telemetryClient  =  new  TelemetryClient(); 
    telemetryClient.TrackException(myExcep); 
}
```

Also refer [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048825/application-insights-logging-exceptions) for more details.

Comment: Thx. To be honest, I would like to remove any AppInsights related code from my application, because this makes it Azure dependent. I don't see the point. I would prefer to always use ILogger which is an abstraction layer.